# Improve Machine Learning Rest Service Performance

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, tomcat7, stanford-nlp

I have a rest service running on tomcat 7 which is doing the following things:

1. Language Detection
2. Stanford NER
3. Stanford Sentiment Analysis
4. Emotion Classification
5. Categorization
6. Summary
7. Theme

As you can guess there are lots of things happening in a single request. 
I want to improve the performance of the rest service and Stanford NER and Stanford sentiment is just taking too much CPU and on a 6 Core Machine with 15 GB RAM on tomcat, I am getting 80% cpu utilization with 10 threads and a throughput of 125. I have tested it with JMeter. The bottleneck is Stanford which takes 90% of the required time in each transaction. I can't scale this in the real world. This is just too slow. Any ideas how to scale my ML service ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Shift-Reduce parser](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/srparser.shtml)? A lot of the time taken is likely from the constituency parser (pulled in by the sentiment model), which is an `O(n^3)` algorithm over the length of the sentence. The shift-reduce parser is a larger memory footprint, but is `O(n)` instead. Otherwise, we may need more fine-grained profiling data to help.

Comment: The throughput increased by 10 to 135 with 70% CPU utilization with the same load. But not that much. 

https://pastebin.com/A2QrSFNy

Comment: Perhaps debug hot spots with JVisualVM? Also, what is throughput measured in? 12 sentences per thread per second is not entirely unreasonable for so much annotation.

Comment: Completely agree with you. But the CPU is a Intel Xeon and it is taking too much CPU. We plan to take this into production soon and want to reduce CPU usage. Any ideas would help.

Answer (score 0):

The real culprit was Deeplearning4j. It was taking most of the CPU.